# flexslider with fixed height while keeping image aspect ratio with overflow hidden

Tags: html, css, flexslider

Been searching for hours now. I want flexslider for a kind of banner rotator on a page. I managed to get a fixed height for the images. But the width of the images get stretched to the browsers borders left and right. I believe what i want is some kine of "overflow: hidden". If browser_width > img_width: show background left and right from the image. If browser_width < img_width: Cut of parts from the image on left and right side. All ways keep the aspect ratio.

Currently the image gets stretched/shrinked horizontally.

HTML

```
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <div class="flexslider_image">
                <img src="/images/alnwick-castle-92607.png" />
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="flexslider_image">
                <img src="/images/server-90389.png" />
            </div>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.slider_container {
  margin-top: -120px;
}

.flexslider {
  border: none !important;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin:0px; 
  padding: 0px; 
}

.slides li {
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.flexslider_image {

}

.flexslider_image img {
  height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: The sources you provide does not show your problem. They are not helping us to reproduce your issue. Please complete the your source example first. Best case is always to provide a run able example.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for some more hours i found a solution.

Do not use an img-tag for the image. Instead use a div with a background image. For details see my html and css.

Another advantage i was locking for anyway is, that one can now more easily place content on the slides.

HTML

```
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <div class="flexslider_background" style="background: url('/images/server-90389.png') no-repeat center;">
                <div class="flexslider_content">
                    <p>
                        Hallo Test 2
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="flexslider_background" style="background: url('/images/minecraft-938604.png') no-repeat center;">
                <div class="flexslider_content">
                    <p>
                        Hallo Test 3
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="flexslider_background" style="background: url('/images/minecraft-669310.jpg') no-repeat center;">
                <div class="flexslider_content">
                    <p>
                        Hallo Test 4
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.slider_container {
  margin-top: -120px;
}

.flexslider {
  border: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  margin:0px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin-bottom: 10px !important;
  background-color: #eee !important;
}

.slides li {
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.flexslider_background {
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flexslider_content {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 145px;
  height: 350px;
  width: 1000px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.flexslider_content p {
  float: left;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```